# Create Mysql Stored Procedure using in vb .NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

How do I create a stored procedure for mysql using VB .NET programmatically?

EDIT:

Apologize to be so brief. I have tried using ExecuteNonQuery provided by MySQL .NET Connector. It prompts me error. Maybe it's because I put "Delimiter $$"?

I know I can create using script (batch file) if I want to send it to my client (as commented below). But my objective is to keep MySQL password safe. So script is not the way.

Comment: This looks like you're competing for least understandable question.

Comment: Why would you want do **create** a stored procedure from VB.NET?  Typically you would create the stored procedure during development and then execute it during run-time from VB.NET.

Comment: @all : The reason for doing this is I want to create new procedure for my client. But I want to make it easy by creating a .NET application that will not intimidate my client. Also, to hide mysql password.

Answer (score 1):

1. Connect to the database.
2. Run the create procedure SQL command using ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: Eh.. It gives me error. I believe it's due to "Delimiter $$". Or did I just do it wrong?